# Exit python properly

Tags: python

I knew that sys.exit() raises an Exit exception, so when I run this I knew it wouldn't exit:

```
In [25]: try:
   ....:     sys.exit()
   ....: except:
   ....:     print "oops"
   ....:     
oops
```

But I thought that os._exit() was meant to exit using a C call, but it's also causing an exception:

```
In [28]: try:
   ....:     os._exit()
   ....: except:
   ....:     print "oops"
   ....:     
oops
```

Is there a way of doing this without killing the PID?

Comment: You should never use `except` without a specific exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `except` without an Exception class, so `sys.exit` will just work fine without triggering the exception handling:

```
>>> import sys
>>> try:
...     sys.exit()
... except Exception:
...     print 'oops'
... 
$
```

There are other exceptions which are triggered with a plain except clause (and in general shouldn't), especially `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Comment: I know this is the conventional wisdom--and even more so, to use a narrowly-specified, *specific* exception. But when you're going to catch every exception and not going to use the exception data (e.g. contra @mgilson's answer), is there really any virtue in `except Exception`? Is there any non-`Exception` possibility that will trigger the `except` clause?

Comment: @ire_and_curses This does exit the process without triggering the exception handler.

Comment: @ms4py - I see. That's interesting! Vote redacted!

Comment: @JonathanEunice Please re-read my answer, it should be more clear now :)

Comment: Why do people lie over and over again? It is very easy to check that sys.exit() throws a SystemExit exception

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but `os._exit` isn't raising an exception -- you calling `os._exit` with the wrong number of arguments is:

```
try:
    os._exit()
except Exception as e:
    print e

#output: _exit() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```